# Organize pillar and states to deploy docker container with Salt

Tags: salt-stack

I'm currently building a deployment system relying on Salt and Docker. For simplicity, let's say I want to deploy a gitlab for 2 clients on the same server.

All the parameters of my apps are stored in Pillar.

> cat /srv/pillar/top.sls

```
'myminion':
- client1.git
- client2.git
```

> cat /srv/pillar/client1/git.sls

```
gitlab:
    client1:
        domains: 
          - git.client1.net
        container_no : 1
```

> cat /srv/pillar/client2/git.sls

```
gitlab:
    client2:
        domains: 
          - git.client2.com
        container_no : 2
```

So far, my Salt states contain specific instructions to deploy different application profiles (Django, NodeJS, Gitlab...). For Gitlab it would be :

> $ cat /srv/salt/profile/gitlab/init.sls

```
{% for app_name,config in pillar.get('gitlab', {}).items() %}
configure reverse proxy for {{app_name}}:
  module.run:
    - name: haproxyctl.add
    - app_name: {{app_name}}
    - domains: {{ config['domains'] }}

[...]
{% endfor %}
```

Everything works fine. But with this I can't deploy one app at a time. I have to do :

> salt myminion state.apply profile.gitlab

And this will deploy all gitlab apps on the server. But I would like to be able to trigger only one app.

I'm not playing with Salt for a long time but I feel this loop on all apps is not a elegant way to do the job. What would be the Salty way to do it ?

Comment: a short guess for now - can you make all states inside of the loop require your first `git.latest` state - this way they should only be executed if there is a new version. Which in fact means you still apply everything - but only all states, if there are changes...

Comment: But if I understand correctly what you say, it also means I have to write a state file for each application whereas now I just have to declare another set of parameters in pillar and my new app is deployed with the gitlab profile state.

Answer (score 1):

What I'd like to say in the comment does not force you to create state files for each application. Think of something like that:

```
{% for app_name,config in pillar.get('gitlab', {}).items() %}
fetch_{{app_name}}:
  git.latest:
    - name: https://mydomain.tld/apps/foo.git
    - target: /var/www/foo
haproxy_{{app_name}}:
  module.run:
    - name: haproxyctl.add
    - app_name: {{app_name}}
    - domains: {{ config['domains'] }}
    - onchanges:
      - git: fetch_{{app_name}}
# all following states should "listen to" the git.latest state
[...]
{% endfor %}
```

This way you can still **not** directly trigger one app to be upgraded on your minion, but in fact salt will only execute all your states regarding one of your apps if there are changes in the repository.

This is not exactly what you've asked for - but it might be a possible solution.

[Read more about requisites](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html).

Comment: Ok, indeed, it's not exactly what I want but I'll give it a try. Thanks.